# Why executing multiple test cases fail to create a driver instance after the previous case finished when using Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mobile, appium

First of all, first time poster, so bear with me, let me know if more information is needed in order to solve this issue.

Secondly, I'm new to Spring-Boot (not so much to automation and Java, but I wouldn't consider myself an expert by any means), so perhaps some of the things you see in the code don't make much sense...

So the problem is I've been trying to learn about Spring Boot, and tried to execute some Appium test cases that I successfully executed using Cucumber, POM and TestNG. Since I wanted to improve how the code looked and make it a bit clearer, I thought I'd give Spring Boot a try.

So I start sort of copying and pasting some of the things from my previous framework over to this new framework I created using start.spring.io, added Serenity and Junit dependencies to the pom.xml file, created a @Bean to start the driver and @Autowired many objects into the tests/steps/pages classes. When I try to execute a single test case (any of the 4 cases I have set up), they are all working and succeed in doing what I had envisioned.

However, when I try to run them all together I get this exception after the first test case execution:
`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?`, now, this (in my opinion), would make sense if I had called "driver.quit()" anywhere in my code, but I know for a fact that I didn't, I'm almost certain there's something I don't know about how Spring Boot and @Beans work which is causing the driver to close after I'm done with the first test case.

I've tried setting the @Bean's @Scope to be "singleton" and "prototype" but that didn't seem to work.

Here's the @Bean driver Set up:

```
public class AppiumLibraries {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppiumLibraries.class);
    @Autowired
    BaseDriver baseDriver;

    @Bean
    @Scope()
    public IOSDriver getIosDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        if (baseDriver.getDriver() == null) {
            logger.info("driver is null, instantiating new driver");
            return baseDriver.setUpIOSDriver();
        }
        logger.info("driver already exists, returning previous driver");
        return (IOSDriver) baseDriver.getDriver();
    }
}
```

Here's the driver setUp:

```
public class BaseDriver {
    private AppiumDriver driver;

    @Value("${iOS.version}")
    private String iOSversion;
    @Value("${iOS.phoneType}")
    private String iOSphoneType;
    @Value("${appium.localHost}")
    private String localHost;

    public IOSDriver setUpIOSDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, iOSversion);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, iOSphoneType);
        capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.LAUNCH_TIMEOUT, 500000);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("commandTimeouts", "60000");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "App/Location");
        driver = new IOSDriver(new URL(localHost), capabilities);
        return (IOSDriver) driver;
    }
```

Here's The Base Test:

```
public class BaseTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppiumLibraries.class);
    @Autowired
    AppiumDriver appiumDriver;
    @Autowired
    private PopUpsPageSteps popUpsPageSteps;
    @Autowired
    private HomePageSteps homePageSteps;
    @Autowired
    private YourAccountPageSteps yourAccountPageSteps;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        appiumDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        logger.info("Appium Driver initialization correct, starting test case");
        if (popUpsPageSteps.verifyDenyButtonIsPresent()){
            logger.info("Closing account first");
            popUpsPageSteps.denyPushNotifications();
            homePageSteps.accessUserAccountInformation();
            yourAccountPageSteps.logOutUser();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate some help since I'm at a loss and can't seem to find anyone with the same issue online...

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to understand what you are doing. You have made your problem too big to explain in a question and as a result you are leaving important information out of it. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and focus on removing every line you don't neef to explain the problem from your project. Then try asking again.

Comment: Thank you so much @M.P.Korstanje! I'll take a look and try again later!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.